# How to install Gatsby@2(beta)

Tags: gatsby

How to install Gatsby@v2? I followed documentation at https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ which is supposed to be docs for the new version. It says to run `npm install --global gatsby-cli`. But this command installs version 1. How do I install 2nd version?

Comment: it looks like the documentation for v1 and v2 is the same in regards to making a new app, there doesnt appear to be a v2 cli

Answer (score 3):

If you want to start a new project from scratch, you can do

```
$ mkdir my-new-app
$ cd my-new-app/
```

Then install the Gatsby and React libraries with Yarn:

```
$ yarn init -y
$ yarn add gatsby@next react react-dom
```

To check if you're using the version 2 of Gatsby, open the `package.json` file in your project folder, you should see something like:

```
"dependencies": {
  "gatsby": "^2.0.0-beta.16",
  "react": "^16.4.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
}
```

---

To update the Gatsby CLI to version 2, in the terminal do:

```
$ npm install --global gatsby-cli@2.0.0-beta.3
```

Then check the CLI version by

```
$ gatsby -v
```

The Gatsby CLI version is not the Gatsby library version, and `gatsby new` may or may not give you the latest version you want, so it is always best to check `package.json` to verify the Gatsby version

Comment: I do this, but `gatsby -v` still gives me version 1. It only workis if I run 2 from node_modules :-(

Comment: `gatsby -v` gives you the version of Gatsby CLI, NOT the library, check my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Gatsby 2.0 is currently tagged as `next` so you need to run `npm install --global gatsby-cli@next`.

Also, you can check which bin file is used if you run `gatsby -v` by running `which gatsby` or also for all your found bins in the $PATH by running `where gatsby`. Whichever paths these commands return, remove the bin files (e.g. `rm /usr/local/bin/gatsby` or something like that) and then run `npm install --global gatsby-cli@next` again.